# flutter_launcher_icons is not generating an android icon

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

this is relevant section of my pubspec.yaml

```
flutter_icons:
  image_path: "assets/icons/app_logo.png"
  andriod: true

  min_sdk_android: 24
```

Running the "flutter_launcher_icons:main" command return the following error

```
     FLUTTER LAUNCHER ICONS (v0.10.0)
 ════════════════════════════════════════════


✕ Could not generate launcher icons

✗ ERROR: InvalidConfigException
No platform specified within config to generate icons for.
pub finished with exit code 2
```

Comment: you're mispelling "android: true"

Comment: Thanks @DungNgo, I swear the amount of times I've gotten screwed over by a typo is crazy.